# Javascript - Giving alert for string input but number

Tags: arrays, string, numbers, prompt, popupwindow

Hi recently I was writing a code which basically askes users to input a cost for any item.
The item name or price are not important so far.
How the system works is that a prompt pops up and asks what is the cost of the item, and when you enter a cost, it asks you again (while loop). When total cost reaches $36, while loop ends and an alert screen pops up saying your shipping is free since it is over $35.

My problem is when I enter string value as a user input it takes the value into cost array and since it goes as Nan value, my cost calculation never end even though it passes $36.

How can I eliminate any string input and do not push it into the array?

Here is my code:

```
while (complete === false) {
var costValue = prompt('Enter the cost of the item?');

//If user click cancel
if (costValue === null) {
alert('Process canceled');
complete = true;} 

//AT THIS LINE HOW CAN I ELIMINATE STRING VALUES
//convert input to a number
userInput = parseInt(costValue);
/push the value into the array
myCost.push(userInput);
```

Answer (score 0):

Leading special character will give you NAN and if you use a special character after the Int value then the parseInt will give you the correct result. You can also use regex to remove all the special characters.

> userInput.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')

You can read about parseInt from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 0):

After you parse your user input into an integer (i.e. using `parseInt` method), then have an `if` statement that checks whether the parsed values is not `NaN`. If so, then only push the parsed value into your array.

```
// TRY parse user input into an integer
userInput = parseInt(costValue);

// only push into your array when it is not `NaN`
if (userInput !== 'NaN') {
// push the value into the array
myCost.push(userInput);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it should work

```
var userInput;
var totalInput=0;
var complete = false;
var costValue;
var numPattern = /^\d+$/;

while (!complete) {
    costValue = prompt('Enter the cost of the item?');

    //If user click cancel
    if (costValue === null) 
    {
        alert('Process canceled');
        complete = true;
    } 

    //convert input to a number if it matches regular expression
    if (costValue.match(numPattern)){
        userInput = parseInt(costValue);

        totalInput+=userInput;
    
        if (totalInput>35) {
          complete=true;
          alert("Cost is $" + totalInput + ". Shipping is free over $35");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand, if you want to go another route, you can check for NaN using this function **isNaN(userInput)** and exclude it from your calculations